# Why does my Windows Vista machine keep switching color schemes?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, colors

I am using Windows Vista 32-bit.

Very often, if I open a folder that contains some .mp4 files (sometimes this does happen other times also), my color theme changes to Vista Basic and this message is displayed:

[image]

If you click on this message, you get this:

[image]

What could the problem be? This is really annoying as it takes a couple to seconds to switch and it switches back if you close the folder.

Comment: What are your pc's specs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation is actually stated in that dialog box. Windows Live Photo Gallery, for whatever reason, is needing to switch the color scheme to Basic. Programs sometimes require this because of memory or window management. In the case of Windows Live Photos, it might be due to some kind of media or thumbnail caching.

Answer (score 1):

Same switching happened to me too, when I touched a mp4 (HD) movie file.

My solution: never show thumbnails.

on Vista: 
Organize | Folder and Search Options | View-tab | check: Always show icons, never thumbnails.

I know... it hurts.

Answer (score 0):

If an application can't deal with Aero, you get flipped back to Windows Basic.

Some (many?) Java applications are like that (in my case, NetBackup Java Console Thing).  I'm surprised that the Windows Live thing causes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It’s most likely due to a buggy video codec for `.mp4` files which is loaded by Windows Explorer when it needs to display the thumbnails.